# custom infowindow box with google maps api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to have a custom infowindow box in the google maps api. If that is not possible, I want to at least remove the rounded corners for the popup. Is this possible?

I tried useing

```
InfoWindow({
    content: "<h3>" + title + "</h3>",
    boxStyle: { styles }
})
```

but boxStyle does nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an InfoBox class from [Google Maps Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries). Or you can write a custom class overriding the default styling